# Why is RETURN QUERY returning a string instead of a TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

This MWE is **NOT** how you would typically solve this problem, however, it is as simple as I can explain the problem I am encountering. I am merely trying to point out 2 things

1. I am doing more than simply returning the contents of a Table
2. What is being returned is NOT being returned as a Table but a String

**Supporting SQL Statements:**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test;

\c test

CREATE TABLE credit_card(
    id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    balance  BIGINT
);
```

**Functions:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_credit_card(
    p_id     BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    id       BIGINT,
    balance  BIGINT
)
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
            credit_card.id,
            credit_card.balance
        FROM
            credit_card
        WHERE
            credit_card.id = p_id;

END $$ LAnguage 'plpgsql';

CREATE FUNCTION pay_with_card(
    p_id     BIGINT,
    p_amount BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    id       BIGINT,
    balance  BIGINT
)
AS $$
DECLARE
    v_balance BIGINT;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        credit_card.balance
    FROM
        credit_card
    INTO
        v_balance
    WHERE
        credit_card.id = p_id;

    IF v_balance < p_amount
    THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    UPDATE
        credit_card
    SET
        balance = credit_card.balance - p_amount;

    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT get_credit_card (p_id);
END $$ LAnguage 'plpgsql';
```

**Populate Table and Call function:**

```
INSERT INTO credit_card
    (balance)
VALUES
    (100);

    SELECT
        pay_with_card (1, 100);
```

**Error:**

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
CREATE TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
INSERT 0 1
psql:test.sql:74: ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type record does not match expected type bigint in column 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function pay_with_card(bigint,bigint) line 24 at RETURN QUERY
```

It took me a long time to figure out that `pay_with_card` is returning a String, or what appears to be a String, instead of a `TABLE(id BIGINT, balance BIGINT)`. With the Python `psycopg2` library, the returned query is

```
[('(1,100)'),]
```

So my entire code is breaking because I can't get the values (unless I hack it and use string manipulation.

**Question:**

How can I fix it so that it returns the correct query like so

```
[(1,100),]
```

Comment: How do you call the function? A set returning function must be used like a table `select * from get_credit_card(...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I was calling it like so: `SELECT pay_with_card (1, 100);` Was that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the hint in horse_with_no_name's comment, you can replace

```
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT get_credit_card (p_id);
```

with

```
    RETURN QUERY SELECT (get_credit_card(p_id)).*;
```

You need some way of expanding the returned record *back* into its constituent fields. (I think horse’s `SELECT * …` has the same effect.)